# Image moves or deletes when displaying with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Recently, I have been working on one of my python3 programs and then I wanted to to open a picture. Here is the code that I used to do it:

```
from PIL import Image

r = Image.open('C:/Users/sudam/OneDrive/Desktop/programming/python/projects/good night app/morning.png' )
r.show()
```

But as soon as I run this code,the windows photo viewer opens and gives and error saying that the specified file was moved. I tried googling this question but all of the answers I got only worked for python2, but not for python3.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have whitespace in your path you need to use the r"string" format.

Also you need to use:
`PIL.ImageShow.show(r)`
to show your image.

It's also recommended to check if the file exist before opening any file.

You can do like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageShow

path =r"C:/Users/sudam/OneDrive/Desktop/programming/python/projects/good night app/morning.png" 
if Path(path).is_file():
    r = Image.open(path)
    ImageShow.show(r)
else:
    print(f'{path} not exist')
```

Comment: It does indeed exist

Comment: I added the 'r' format too but it doesn;t work either

Comment: An `r` prefix is only needed when specifying a Windows file path with backslash \ characters in it — so is not required here.

Comment: @sudam: However, since the path *does* contain space characters you might need to use `'"C:/Users/sudam/OneDrive/Desktop/programming/python/projects/good night app/morning.png"'` — note the mixture of single and double quotes.

Comment: The path is entered correctly,But the image viewer only displays the image for about 0.5 seconds and then errors out.It says,''tmpbdtqz918.PNG' It appears that the file was moved or renamed'.

Comment: Try to copy the image to local folder in your computer, maybe the onedrive path makes the problem.